# wxtooltip wxwidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

We have built an application using wxWidgets in C++ and use wxToolTips to provide some information the end user when he points the mouse at something on the application. however I notice that the tooltips are automatically packaged neatly in new lines in mac. but in windows it comes as one single line,which doesnt look very appealing.

in mac: "this helps u increase the \n 
          brightness of the image\n
           ........................."

in win : "this helps u increase the brightness of the image............................"

Can anyone help me with this? I do not want to use new line characters and hardcode the tooltip into multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a static function `wxToolTip::SetMaxWidth(int width)` on MSW that sets the width in pixels. You must call it before setting the wxToolTip, according to the docs.

Comment: Thanks John, but i believe the function SetMaxWidth is available only with wxWidgets 2.8.10 and higher. I use 2.8.2.

Comment: Hmmm...then I think you would need to call the Windows API directly to set the max width. In `msw\tooltip.cpp`, wxWidgets 2.9.2 uses `SendTooltipMessage(GetToolTipCtrl(), TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH, wxUIntToPtr(maxWidth));` which becomes a message like `::SendMessage((HWND)hwnd, msg, 0, (LPARAM)lParam)`, so if you can grab the `hwnd` it seems possible with a little work.